# passing two domain objects in one json in grails jax rs

Tags: json, authentication, grails

I am using jaxrs:0.10 and I have default generated resources for a domain `OrderDetails`. And the client will `POST` json which will contain domain `OrderDetails` object as well as other two parameters `userName` and `password`, so that only authenticated users consume the resource. I can simply save to database for domain `OrderDetails` only without authentation(i.e.the JSON is same as the domain.) by posting a JSON but by adding the other two parameters for authentication is a bit different thing. How to accomplish this task, my need is :

1)The client posts the json with userName,password and `OrderDetails` object.
2)I need to authenticate the user credentials for `OrderDetails` object to save to the database.

For time being user credentials will the static.

My code for domain `OrderDetails` is :

```
class OrderDetails {

    Date orderDate
    Long orderNumber

    Float subTotal
    Float shipping
    Float discount
    Float netTotalPaid
    boolean creditApplied

    Long transactionId
    String specialInstruction
    DeliveryStatus deliveryStatus

    Long memberId
    String localOffice

    static constraints = {
        orderDate nullable: true
        orderNumber nullable: true

        subTotal nullable: true
        shipping nullable: true
        discount nullable: true
        netTotalPaid nullable: true
        creditApplied nullable: true

        transactionId nullable: true
        specialInstruction nullable: true
        deliveryStatus nullable: true

        memberId nullable: true
        localOffice nullable: true
    }
}
```

And the generated Resources are :

```
@Path('/api/v1/orderDetails')
@Consumes(['application/json'])
@Produces(['application/json'])
class OrderDetailsCollectionResource {

    def orderDetailsResourceService

    @POST
    Response create(OrderDetails dto) {
        created orderDetailsResourceService.create(dto)
    }

    @GET
    Response readAll() {
        ok orderDetailsResourceService.readAll()
    }

    @Path('/{id}')
    OrderDetailsResource getResource(@PathParam('id') Long id) {
        new OrderDetailsResource(orderDetailsResourceService: orderDetailsResourceService, id:id)
    }
}
```

And :

```
@Consumes(['application/json'])
@Produces(['application/json'])
class OrderDetailsResource {

    def orderDetailsResourceService
    def id

    @GET
    Response read() {
        ok orderDetailsResourceService.read(id)
    }

    @PUT
    Response update(OrderDetails dto) {
        dto.id = id
        ok orderDetailsResourceService.update(dto)
    }

    @DELETE
    void delete() {
        orderDetailsResourceService.delete(id)
    }
}
```

Comment: My suggestion ist to use a business object that contains all your objects you want to send as json. Just like a wrappr object.

Comment: Can u be more descriptive ?

Answer (score 0):

Your wrapper:

```
class AuthOrder {
   OrderDetails orderDetails;
   Token userToken;
   Password password;
}
```

Now you expect an AuthOrder-Json-Object instead of an OrderDetails. In your GET/PUT/DELETE-Operations you read the user and password and check if it is allowed to do the job. Then pass on the OrderDetails-Object.

For the json-rest-authentication in general I suggest you to read [how-do-people-handle-authentication-for-restful-apis-technology-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551080/how-do-people-handle-authentication-for-restful-apis-technology-agnostic)

**EDIT: Example for @PUT;**

```
@Consumes(['application/json'])
@Produces(['application/json'])
class OrderDetailsResource {

def orderDetailsResourceService
def id

@GET
Response read() {
    ok orderDetailsResourceService.read(id)
}

@PUT
Response update(AuthOrder dto) {
    if (validateUser(dto.getUserName, dto.getUserPassword)) {
       OrderDetails orderDetails= dto.getOrderDetails();
       dto.id = id
       ok orderDetailsResourceService.update(dto)
    } else 
       //not ok response
    }
}

 @DELETE
 void delete() {
    orderDetailsResourceService.delete(id)
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks !! I will implement and reply.

Comment: Please add more description.